# How can I remove the gap when the song replays in the html audio tag?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

When I make use of the 'loop' attribute on the html5 audio element there seems to be a gap when the song replays. Is there a simple way to remove this gap?

**code:**

```
<audio controls loop preload>
  <source src="http://www.phatdrumloops.com/audio/wav/ifineededs.wav" type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

**working fiddle example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/rmwumaz7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually is a problem by the audio tag. You can however try to minimise the effect by doing something like this:

```
var audio = new Audio('http://www.phatdrumloops.com/audio/wav/ifineededs.wav')
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
            var buffer = .1
            if(this.currentTime > this.duration - buffer){
                this.currentTime = 0
                this.play()
            }}, false);
 audio.play()
```

**Edit**: According to your comments, I've digged a bit deeper. This is what I found:
https://github.com/Hivenfour/SeamlessLoop

Problem here is, you need to provide the correct length of the track in ms (the track you want to loop)

See a fiddle here.
https://jsbin.com/simuvoduhi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This didn't seem to help, i tried it with a .wav file this time in combination with your solution : https://jsfiddle.net/rmwumaz7/3/

Comment: Mhm. To be honest, I have absolutely no lag. Perfect loop on my mac.

Comment: I have like a 200ms delay between them, almost perfect but still I notice the gap. And this is noticeable when you try to play notes over it with a guitar.

Comment: I had a perfect loop when I played it in Audacity, the program where I made this loop with.

Comment: And with this example it sometimes loops perfectly and somtimes with a gap : https://jsfiddle.net/rmwumaz7/4/

Comment: could you provide the *exact* length of the wav file in ms?

Comment: @JimPeeters see my edits

Comment: Ive seen that solution but the problem is that I need to find a way with php or javascript to get the exact duration of an audio file when uploading it. So i was trying to find a solution that didn't require me to know the duration of the file. But I guess there is no other option.

Comment: @JimPeeters with a little bit of tweaking, it should be possible to read the duration within javascript with something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_audio_duration.asp